# How can I fix tuple index out of range

Tags: python

I am a beginner of Python. Trying to create a function to calculate volume of shape.
If the shape is "sphere" then it will return the `volume_sphere`.
If the shape is "cone", then it will return the `volume_cone`.
I don't know why I am getting `IndexError: tuple index out of range`
my code as below:

```
def calculate_volume(shape, dimension):
    r = dimension[0]
    h = dimension[1]
    Volume_Sphere = 4 / 3 * 3.14 * r ** 3
    Volume_Cone = 1 / 3 * (3.14 * r ** 2 * h)
    if shape == 'sphere':
        return Volume_Sphere
    elif shape == 'cone':
        return Volume_Cone
    else:
        return "invalid shape"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(calculate_volume('sphere', (2,)))
```

Comment: `(2,)` that you pass as `dimension` is one-element tuple, so there is no is `dimension[1]`.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. If it is correct in your code but not on Stack Overflow, please see [formatting help](/help/formatting).

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Also, why assign a height and calculate the volume of a sphere when shape is `cone`? Those things should be in their respective `if` statements.

Comment: Thank you all. I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the indentation in the code you sent is not correct, please fix that.

The problem in your code is that in the last line, the `dimension` argument, which is supposed to be a tuple, does not have two elements. Your function clearly uses the first element of the tuple as the radius, and the second element as the height, and you have not input the value of height.

Here is the fixed code:

```py
def calculate_volume(shape,dimension):
    r = dimension[0]
    h = dimension[1]
    Volume_Sphere = 4/3*3.14*r**3
    Volume_Cone = 1/3*(3.14*r**2*h)
    if (shape == 'sphere'):
        return Volume_Sphere
    elif (shape == 'cone'):
        return Volume_Cone
    else:
        return ("invalid shape")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(calculate_volume('cone',(2,3)))
```

Notice that in the last line instead of `(2,)`, I have written `(2,3)`, so I have input the value of height, which was not the case in the original code.

Comment: I am a beginner of Python. Sorry for the trouble. I mean that if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(calculate_volume('sphere', (2,))) then this will output the error:index out of range.

Comment: thank you, i got it

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that calculate_volume() is only concerned with spheres and cones. On that basis, the height of the object is only relevant if you need the volume of a cone. Therefore we can do this:-

```
def calculate_volume(r, h=-1):
    return 1/3*(3.14*r**2*h) if h > 0 else 4/3*3.14*r**3


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(calculate_volume(2))
    print(calculate_volume(2, 3))
```

In the first case, we get the volume of a sphere with radius 2 and in the second case we get the volume of a cone with radius 2 and height of 3

Comment: thank you, i get it!